# Onsen UI 2.0 + Reactでのons-navigatorについて

Tags: onsen-ui

Onsen UI 2.0をReactで使おうとしています。

Onsen UIの[ons-navigator](https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-navigator.html)を利用した画面遷移を実装したいのですが、実装方法がわかりません。

リファレンスでは、`ons-navigator`の`var`属性を利用してnavigatorを参照できるようにしていますが、`var`属性はAngularのみ対応しているようです。

Reactではどのよに実装すればいいでしょうか？
なにか、情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。